Understanding $\mathbb{P}_i\left(J_1 \leq t, Y_1=j, S_2>t\right)$ in Continuous-Time Markov Chains
I am working through Theorem 3.2.1 in Markov Chains by Norris, and I want to understand the following inequality under the condition $q_{i j}>0$ :
\begin{equation*}
p_{i j}(t) \geq \mathbb{P}_i\left(J_1 \leq t, Y_1=j, S_2>t\right)=\left(1-e^{-q_i t}\right) \pi_{i j} e^{-q_j t}>0
\end{equation*}
I would like to understand:

How this inequality is derived step by step from the definitions of continuous-time Markov chains.
How the equality $\mathbb{P}_i\left(J_1 \leq t, Y_1=j, S_2>t\right)=\left(1-e^{-q_i t}\right) \pi_{i j} e^{-q_j t}$ is explicitly obtained. Specifically how the terms $\left(1-e^{-q_i t}\right), \pi_{i j}$, and $e^{-q_j t}$ are connected to the embedded jump chain and the holding times.



The chain can start in state $i$ and be in state $j$ at time $t$ in various ways. One way is for the chain's first jump (which occurs at time $J_1$) to happen at or before time $t$ and to be a jump directly from $i$ to $j$, and then for the sojourn in state $j$ to last longer than $t$, so the chain is still in state $j$ at time $t$.
The quantity on the left side of your inequality, $p_{ij}(t)$, is the probability that the chain starts in state $i$ and is in state $j$ at time $t$.
The probability $\Bbb P_i(J_1\le t, Y_1=j, S_2>t)$ can be computed as follows.
The first-jump time $J_1$ is exponentially distributed with rate $q_i$. Independently of the time $J_1$, the jump at that time is from $i$ to $j$ with probability $\pi_{ij}=q_{ij}/q_i$. Given that $Y_1=j$, the distribution of $S_2$ is exponential with rate $q_j$, independent of $S_1$. Therefore
$$
\Bbb P_i(J_1\le t, Y_1=j, S_2>t)=(1-e^{-q_i t})\pi_{ij}e^{-q_j t}.
$$
This shows
$$
p_{ij}(t)\ge (1-e^{-q_i t})\pi_{ij} e^{-q_j t}.
$$
